# When using the strafter function in sparql it doesn't run because of an invalid line error

Tags: sparql

When using the STRAFTER in a sparql query it gives back an invalid line error, I'm not sure what is wrong with the line of code.

```
STRAFTER("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Xbox_One", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/")
```

I want the result to look like this ->

Xbox_One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the result to a variable.

```
SELECT ?LocalPart

{?s ?p ?o

BIND (STRAFTER("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Xbox_One", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/") AS ?LocalPart)

} 

LIMIT 1
```